# pivot longer two groups of columns with the same set of suffixes, mostly an issue of correct regex

Tags: r, regex, pivot

I have a data frame with something like:

borg_dx, borg_sx, borg_dominant, borg_nondominant

which contains the integer values of the borg scale for the right, left, dominant and non dominant side.

Then i have another set of columns called:

borg_category_dx, borg_category_sx, borg_category_dominant, borg_category_nondominant,

which has character values for the category of borg (no effort, some effort, ecc.)

```
df1 <- data.frame( borg_dx = c(0,1), borg_sx = c(3,1), borg_dominant = c(3,1), borg_nondominant = c(0,8), borg_category_dx = c("no effort", "no effort"), borg_category_sx = c("light effort", "no effort"), borg_category_dominant = c("light effort", "no effort"), borg_category_nondominant = c("no effort", "high effort"))
```

I want to pivot the data frame into a long format where one column is the side, one column is the borg value and one column is the borg category, like this:

df_long  <-  data.frame(side = c("dx", "sx", "dom", "nondom", "dx", "sx", "dom", "nondom"), borg_value = c(0,3,3,0,1,1,1,8), borg_category = c("no effort", "no effort", "light effort", "no effort", "light effort", "no effort", "no effort", "high effort"))

if i just wanted to pivot borg values or categories, i could just do:

```
pivot_longer(
      cols = starts_with("borg"),
      names_to = "side",
      names_prefix = "borg_",
      values_to = "borg_value")
```

but having to send all suffixes (dx, sx, dominant, nondominant) to one column called side, and the values to two columns, i found from other answers that i should use something like:

```
 pivot_longer(
  cols = starts_with("borg"),
  names_to = c(".value", "side"),
  names_prefix = "borg",
  names_pattern = ??????
```

except i have no idea how to phrase the regex bit. i don't know if i should just rename the columns to use just one underscore and a different separator.

Comment: Please adjust your example code so it runs. e.g. `side = c("dx", "sx", ...)` instead of `side = c(dx, sx ...)`

Comment: Please provide example data.frame representing Your problem and the output You're expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it sounds like your data looks something like below.

`dput()` output for replication:

```r
df0 <- structure(list(borg_dx = c( 0L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 0L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 10L ), 
                       borg_sx = c( 9L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 9L ), 
                       borg_dominant = c( 0L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 10L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 0L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 5L ), 
                       borg_nondominant = c( 8L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 3L ), 
                       borg_category_dx = c( "Rest", "Really Easy", "Really Easy", "Really Hard", "Hard", "Really Hard", "Rest", "Really Easy", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Really Hard", "Hard", "Really Hard", "Moderate", "Sort of Hard", "Moderate", "Really, Really, Hard", "Hard", "Rest", "Sort of Hard", "Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Moderate", "Really Hard", "Rest", "Moderate", "Really Hard", "Hard", "Rest", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Really Hard", "Really Easy", "Sort of Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Rest", "Really, Really, Hard", "Moderate", "Really Easy", "Hard", "Really Hard", "Hard", "Really Easy", "Rest", "Sort of Hard", "Hard", "Really Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Rest", "Really, Really, Hard", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race" ), 
                       borg_category_sx = c( "Really, Really, Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Rest", "Rest", "Sort of Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Really Easy", "Moderate", "Sort of Hard", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Rest", "Moderate", "Really Hard", "Really Easy", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Sort of Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Really Hard", "Rest", "Really Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Moderate", "Hard", "Rest", "Hard", "Hard", "Really Hard", "Moderate", "Really Easy", "Really Hard", "Sort of Hard", "Rest", "Really Easy", "Rest", "Rest", "Sort of Hard", "Moderate", "Rest", "Really Hard", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Hard", "Really Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Rest", "Rest", "Really, Really, Hard" ), 
                       borg_category_dominant = c( "Rest", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Hard", "Rest", "Really Hard", "Rest", "Really, Really, Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Sort of Hard", "Really Hard", "Rest", "Rest", "Really Hard", "Moderate", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Hard", "Rest", "Sort of Hard", "Sort of Hard", "Really Hard", "Really Easy", "Moderate", "Really, Really, Hard", "Sort of Hard", "Rest", "Hard", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Really, Really, Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Sort of Hard", "Moderate", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Really Hard", "Really Hard", "Sort of Hard", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Rest", "Really Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Really Easy", "Rest", "Really, Really, Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Rest", "Really, Really, Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Really Hard", "Hard" ), 
                       borg_category_nondominant = c( "Really, Really, Hard", "Moderate", "Really Hard", "Sort of Hard", "Rest", "Really Hard", "Sort of Hard", "Moderate", "Rest", "Really Hard", "Sort of Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Really Hard", "Rest", "Really Easy", "Really, Really, Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Really Hard", "Rest", "Rest", "Hard", "Hard", "Rest", "Really, Really, Hard", "Really Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Really, Really, Hard", "Sort of Hard", "Really Easy", "Really Hard", "Rest", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Really Hard", "Really Easy", "Sort of Hard", "Hard", "Really Hard", "Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Hard", "Really Hard", "Hard", "Really, Really, Hard", "Really Hard", "Really Hard", "Really Easy", "Maximal: Just like my hardest race", "Rest", "Moderate" ) ), 
                  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-50L))
```

As a tibble:

```r
dplyr::as_tibble(df0)
#> # A tibble: 50 × 8
#>    borg_dx borg_sx borg_dominant borg_nondominant borg_category_dx              
#>      <int>   <int>         <int>            <int> <chr>                         
#>  1       0       9             0                8 Rest                          
#>  2       2       8            10                3 Really Easy                   
#>  3       2       0            10                6 Really Easy                   
#>  4       7       0             5                4 Really Hard                   
#>  5       5       4             1                1 Hard                          
#>  6       6       9             6                6 Really Hard                   
#>  7       0      10             0                4 Rest                          
#>  8       2       2             8                3 Really Easy                   
#>  9      10       3             9                1 Maximal: Just like my hardest…
#> 10       7       4             4                6 Really Hard                   
#> # ℹ 40 more rows
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: borg_category_sx <chr>, borg_category_dominant <chr>,
#> #   borg_category_nondominant <chr>
```

The `name_prefix` argument of `pivot_longer()` removes the prefix before
the `name_pattern` is applied. In this case the prefix is useful to tell the
borg values and borg categories apart. In `name_pattern` we use parenthesis
to define two extraction groups; the first one “(.*)” captures everything up
until the second underscore, leaving everything after the underscore for the second group.

```r
library(tidyr)

df0 |>
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("borg"),
    names_to = c(".value", "side"),
    names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)"
  )
#> # A tibble: 200 × 3
#>    side         borg borg_category                     
#>    <chr>       <int> <chr>                             
#>  1 dx              0 Rest                              
#>  2 sx              9 Really, Really, Hard              
#>  3 dominant        0 Rest                              
#>  4 nondominant     8 Really, Really, Hard              
#>  5 dx              2 Really Easy                       
#>  6 sx              8 Really, Really, Hard              
#>  7 dominant       10 Maximal: Just like my hardest race
#>  8 nondominant     3 Moderate                          
#>  9 dx              2 Really Easy                       
#> 10 sx              0 Rest                              
#> # ℹ 190 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you, i edited the question to make some reproducible code, but this is exactly what i needed!

What i don't understand is why would the pattern "(.*)_(.*)" catch everything before the SECOND underscore, instead of the first.

Comment: @FrancescoFavro because of the greedyness of the asterisk. If you want to capture to the first underscore use a lazy regex pattern ie `(.*?)_(.*)`

Comment: I see... i think? could you direct me to a good resource to learn regex syntax? because i'm sure it makes sense to you that the asterisk is greedy and the ? is lazy, but to me it's just words at the moment